# CSS left-attribute: 50% OR 500px, whichever is greater?

Tags: css, html

I have a div that has the following css: position: fixed; height: 100%; left: 50%;

Is it possible to have this element at `left: 50%` in situations when the 50% of browser width equals >500px and `left: 500px` when 50% of the browser width equals <500px?

I.e the element would be positioned at the larger value: `500px` OR `50%` IF `50% > 500px`.

Thanks

Comment: I know, I was wondering if there was a css solution using conditional css

Comment: #1 rule of conditional CSS is not to use it. If you really want conditional css - have a script that generates it, based on input parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to use media queries

Here is the W3 spec: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/davetayls/CTwuc/3/embedded/result/

And the code: http://jsfiddle.net/davetayls/CTwuc/3/

Answer (score 0):

Its all depends upon your page. And as far as possible don't apply % to any property. Give them particular unit measurement.